# wrong encoding in a csv generated by a PHP script

Tags: php, macos, encoding, csv, header

The CSV is always read by MAC users, so I guess this is a Mac problem

I'm generating a csv file with this piece of code (thx SO :p)

```
<?php
include("../include/include.php");
$file_new_export = '../temp/new_hve_full.php';
$query = "select * from mytable";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Sql error : " . mysql_error());

if (!$result)
    die('Couldn\'t fetch records');
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $hve_biodiv = unserialize($row['hve_a']);
    $hve_ferti = unserialize($row['hve_b']);
    $hve_phyto = unserialize($row['hve_c']);
    $hve_irri = unserialize($row['hve_d']);
    $hve_eco = unserialize($row['hve_e']);

    $content[] = array_merge(array_values($hve_a), array_values($hve_b), array_values($hve_c), array_values($hve_d), array_values($hve_e));
    if ($i == 0)
        $headers = array_merge(array_keys($hve_a), array_keys($hve_b), array_keys($hve_c), array_keys($hve_d), array_keys($hve_e));

    $i++;
}

$fp = fopen($file_new_export, 'w');
if ($fp && $result) {

    fwrite($fp, '<?php ');
    fwrite($fp, 'header(\'Content-Type: application/csv; charset=iso-8859-1\');');
    fwrite($fp, 'header(\'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="export_hve.csv"\');');
    fwrite($fp, 'header(\'Pragma: no-cache\');');
    fwrite($fp, 'header(\'Expires: 0\');');
    fwrite($fp, '?>');

    fputcsv($fp, $headers, ';');
    foreach ($content as $fields) {
        fputcsv($fp, $fields, ';');
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

Everything works fine but I get some letters with wrong encoding, typically instead of "é" I get "È" it s close but not good...

If the content-type and the filename are swith to an html or a txt file then all caracters are well displayed, it seems only to affect csv files, if I switch the encoding on the excel for mac to west european it still not working...

Don't know what to do here, I m looking for a simple solution not encoding all files to utf8 or things like this cause there s a lot of data...Everything is in iso8859-1 according to the my settings (BDD/IDE/PHP encoding)...

Thx for help

Comment: What do you see when you open the file in a text editor?

Comment: I remember having encoding issues with excel (and only excel) when importing CSV's. If you open the file in some other Mac program (textmate, smultron, whatever), is the encoding messed up then as well? Is the actual PHP file also encoded (when being saved) in 8859-1?

Comment: It s fine if open with an editor(Komodo)but if it's open by excel or Numbers(2.0.5) then wrong caracters are displayed...If I switch to western european in excel nothing change and I didn't find this settings on Numbers (I'm going to have a closer look)

Comment: @Stefan only fail with excel/number and yes I carefully create the generated file straight from my netbeans IDE where the project is iso-8859-1 so I guess it's ok

Comment: if it opens right in other programs, blame excel/numbers. I think I had to manually tell excel what encoding to import the file in.

Comment: Could it maybe even be just a [CRLF/LF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) Problem

Comment: Did you set your database connection charset with `mysql_set_charset('latin1')`?

Answer (score 8):

Well i should think that this, may solve your problem. Just put this line at the top of your php file (before any includes):

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');
```

More info at: [Enconding Type Header](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-set-content-encoding-type-header/)

This is because it will encode the file correctly.

gl,
Paulo Bueno

Comment: That won't fix my problem as the website is already iso-8859-1 compliant, apprently it looks like excel mac cannot handle this charset :/

Comment: have u readed the link info? ... "Although I'd specified the content type to be iso-8859-1 it was sill showing as UTF-8 so the page wasn't rendering correctly." and also try to see the "Firefox has a useful function to see what the web server is telling the browser. Right-click the page and select the 'View Page Info' option."

Answer (score 5):

.csv is just plain file text that happens to have structured data within. There's no way for the innards of the file to indicate which character set was used. You're forcing a download of the file via the "content-disposition: attachment", so the HTTP header indicating character set will only be in effect for the duration of the download. After that, it's just another file on the hard-drive.

If you're intending this data to be used in Excel exclusively, then I'd suggest using [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com) to generate a real Excel file, which will not have these translation problems.

Answer (score 4):

erk, scary.

There is a lot of messy, redundant code in the while loop - and you should write the output within the same loop you're reading your input in. And you're not writing a csv file - you're writing a PHP file - which is extremely dangerous.

```
include("../include/include.php");
$result = mysql_query("select * from mytable") || die mysql_error();

header('Content-Type: application/csv; charset=iso-8859-1');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="export_hve.csv"');
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  print mkcsv($row) . "\n";
}
exit;
function mkcsv($a)
{
 foreach ($a as $k=>$v) {
   if (!preg_match("/^([0-9.])*$/", $v) {
       $a[$k]="'" . addslashes($v) . "'";
   }
 }
 return implode(',',$a) . "\n";
}
```

Now, on to the problem.

What character set are you using on the database? How did you verify the encoding was wrong? And was wrong because of the way you extracted it? i.e. did you do a hexdump on the data and check that the 0x233 had been converted to 0x200?

Try:

```
mysql_query('set names latin1');
```

before you execute your SELECT statement.

Comment: Learn something new everyday, great post!

Comment: That's intersting for the programming part, I wonder if ive to write the file in the loop or not, I was thinking it was more clean to open the file, write all the inputs in it then close it...

Comment: mysql_query('set names latin1');
this I try with no change at all, if I try with UTF8 then it change my value to NULL!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be setting the content-type for your export file correctly through the header, but I am curious if the problem doesn't lie in your database charset.  If you are storing your data in MySQL with a different charset than iso-8859-1, then it might cause some funky issues if trying to be stored/displayed as such.

---

Sniffing around a little more I found the following:
**Wikipedia:**
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1

> For the character encoding commonly mislabeled as "ISO-8859-1", see
>   Windows-1252.

---

**MySQL:**
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-mysql.html
To figure out the default charset of your database, try running the query:

```
SHOW VARIABLES;
```

The list it returns should have a variable called

```
character_set_database
```

which from the MySQL Reference is:

> The character set used by the default database. The server sets this variable whenever the default database changes. If there is no default database, the variable has the same value as character_set_server.

Comment: That look like an intersting issue, I looked at the database via phpmyadmin and each table individually has a latin1_swedish_ci encoding but for the whole thing it's utf8_general_ci ...I m'gonna make some tests...

Comment: @afuzzyllama I don't think that collation can make text garbled. It's a charset problem, not a collation problem.

Comment: @Karolis - Agreed, I think I was thinking about charset when I was saying collation.  Edit made.

Comment: it s there a command line to get the charset of a whole database ? cause phpmyadmin is not so clear about it ?

Answer (score 1):

UTF8 has been created to handle a large variety of character sets including the French language, Spanish, ... language sets. Using UTF8 is recommended.

That said, In PHP, when working on a Mac platform, you need to use the iconv() fonction to perform the conversions. For instance, you can do the following:

```
<?php
$unprocessed_string = "Éléphant";
$processed_spring = iconv('MACINTOSH', 'UTF8', $unprocessed_string);
?>
```

Feel free to replace UTF8 with whatever encoding type you wish to use.

The tricky part is that you may be using a file containing a text copied from another software. I have personally noticed that such text may already be in UTF8 and in that case, no conversion will be necessary.

(edited)

Additional note:

This will only affect the content manipulated from the file. If you still experience trouble displaying the content, make sure to use the header() function in PHP to force the encoding type and "charset" of the whole page.

Comment: actually this code is kind of working (already use that in the past), like:   $hve= iconv('ISO-8859-1', 'MACINTOSH', $hve); Then it will be well display on the csv file (but not in the browser), my only question is why ? all the chain is iso8859-1 from databse to charset to editor setting so that means excel mac cannot handle iso8859-1 by default ? it s really strange...

Comment: I have edited the original post to add the solution for that. The encoding of the page must match that of the content being displayed. UTF8 will not be well displayed on ISO-8859-1 and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

it's working. Enjoy
just put this line before fputcsv. and it will convert to utf8.

```
foreach ($input_array as $line) {
        $line = array_map("utf8_decode", $line);
        fputcsv($temp_memory, $line, $delimiter);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try re-encoding it using [mb_convert_encoding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)